# After modifying the throughput of a DynamoDB table, where can I see the new throughput value before it gets active?

Tags: dynamodb

After modifying the throughput of a table in DynamoDB, the "Modify Throughput" is greyed out:

[image]

Where can I see the new throughput value before it gets active? Sometimes it takes a while for a throughput to get applied, especially for large values, and I would like to check whether the person (myself or colleague) who changed the throughput didn't make a mistake.

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So ideas are still welcome!

Answer (score -1):

I came across similar problem. So thinking to make some sort of series of describe table

```
DescribeTableResult describeTableResult = client.describeTable('tableName')
```

And put it in while loop until settings are applied. That could give rough idea how much time does it take to apply settings.

Comment: The question is not how long it takes to apply the change but how to view the newly applied throughput value immediately after you've modified it, when the "Modify Throughput" control is disabled.